# How to get tables from a word file and store them into a datagridview?

Tags: c#, ms-word

i am working with c# on VS 2013. in my program, i want to get a word file as an input from to an openfiledialog. then i want to access into it and extract the tables which exist on it and finally, store them into a datagridview. 
please i need a Tutorial to follow.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are working with OpenXML SDK.. In that case maybe something like that will give you access to all of the tables:

```
Body body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
foreach (Table t in body.Descendants<Table>())
{
...
}
```

See this as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850835(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: i just add the word library and i am not working with the openXML SDK